# Accessing AzureDataLake Gen2 from Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

I would like to read data from Azure DataLake Gen 2 from Databricks. I have an Owner role for both and read/write/execute rights. DataLake allows access from the Vnet where Databricks are added. I try two methods: Auth2 and passthrough (preferable method).

For the passthrough method I tried the following code in Databricks notebook and I set up all the prerequisites ([from this git](https://github.com/devlace/azure-databricks-storage/blob/master/notebooks/directconnect_adpassthrough_py.py)):

```
# MAGIC 1. Azure Databricks Premium Plan.
# MAGIC 2. Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2: Databricks Runtime 5.3 or above.
# MAGIC 3. High concurrency clusters, which support only Python and SQL. [Enabled AD Passthrough checkbox under Advanced Options](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/adls-passthrough.html#enable-passthrough-for-a-cluster)
# MAGIC 4. User needs to have [Storage Data Blob Owner/Contributor/Reader role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal#rbac-roles-for-blobs-and-queues) OR [appropriate ACL permissions (R/W/E) on ADLA Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control#access-control-lists-on-files-and-directories) is granted

# COMMAND ----------

# Try to access file
# You'll need data.csv at root of container/filesystem
df = spark.read.csv("abfss://<STORAGE_CONTAINER>@<STORAGE_ACCOUNT>.dfs.core.windows.net/data.csv")
display(df)
```

And the error appears: `"abfss://<STORAGE_CONTAINER>@<STORAGE_ACCOUNT>.dfs.core.windows.net/data.csv" has invalid authority`

For the Auth method, I use the following code:

```
# Databricks notebook source
# MAGIC %md
# MAGIC ## Azure DataLake Gen2
# MAGIC 
# MAGIC Pre-requisites:
# MAGIC 1. [Create Service Principle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-        us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal)
# MAGIC 1. Service Principle has [Storage Data Blob     Owner/Contributor/Reader role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-    us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal#rbac-roles-for-blobs-and-    queues) OR [appropriate ACL permissions (R/W/E) on ADLA Gen2]    (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-    access-control#access-control-lists-on-files-and-directories) is granted
# MAGIC 2. **Databricks Runtime 5.2** or above
# MAGIC 3. ADLS Gen2 storage account in the **same region** as your Azure     Databricks workspace

# COMMAND ----------

# Set spark configuration
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type", "OAuth")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type",     "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id", "    <SERVICE_PRINCIPLE_CLIENT_ID>")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret", "    <SERVICE_PRINCIPLE_SECRET>")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint",     "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<DIRECTORY_TENANT_ID>/oauth2/token")

# COMMAND ----------

# Try to access file
# You'll need data.csv at root of container/filesystem
df =     spark.read.csv("abfss://<STORAGE_CONTAINER>@<STORAGE_ACCOUNT>.dfs.core.windows    .net/data.csv")
display(df)
```

An the error is `STORAGE_ACCOUNT.dfs.core.windows.net/STORAGE_CONTAINER//?action=getAccessControl&amp;timeout=90`

What could be wrong here? I have read/write/execute rights.

Do I identify correctly STORAGE_ACCOUNT and STORAGE_CONTAINER?

I have the following file system (example):

[image]

For example, I would like to read data.csv in shared-read-and-write.
Would this code correct for that:

```
 df =     spark.read.csv("abfss://<STORAGE_CONTAINER>@<STORAGE_ACCOUNT>.dfs.core.windows    .net/data.csv")
```

->

```
 df =     spark.read.csv("abfss://shared-read-and-write@DATALAKE GEN2_NAME.dfs.core.windows.net/shared-read-and-write/data.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

create a mount location first in Databricks like below mentioned code :

```
clientid="<clientId>"
credential="<clientSecret>"
storageAccountKey="<storageAccountKey>"
refreshurl="<url>"

configs = {"dfs.adls.oauth2.access.token.provider.type": "ClientCredential",
           "dfs.adls.oauth2.client.id": clientid,
           "dfs.adls.oauth2.credential": credential,
           "dfs.adls.oauth2.refresh.url": refreshurl}

dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "adl://<accountname>.azuredatalakestore.net/<path of adls>",
  mount_point = "/mnt/adls",  extra_configs = configs)
```

By default it takes dbfs location,adls will not work even if you are in same resource group
Use spark.read.csv("/mnt/adls/")
Hpe this helps

Comment: FWIW, Databricks no longer recommends mounting external data locations to Databricks Filesystem. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/storage/azure-storage